# Django and Django CMS Error

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've just done a fresh install of Django and Django-CMS from the ground up (including a brand new virtualenv and python build). I'm getting this bizzarre error.. google has been no help. Ideas?

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

In template /Users/bdunlay/python/python-2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_cms2.1.0.beta3-py2.5.egg/cms/templates/cms/new.html, error at line 37
```

Here's the line:

```
37: <li>Log into <a href="{% url admin:index %}">admin</a> and <a href="{% url pages-root %}admin/cms/page/add/">add</a> some pages.</li>
```

more stuff

```
/Users/bdunlay/python/python-2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.5.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _populate
    return '<%s %s (%s:%s) %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.urlconf_name, self.app_name, self.namespace, self.regex.pattern)
def _populate(self):
    lookups = MultiValueDict()
    namespaces = {}
    apps = {}
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
-->     p_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern ...
        if p_pattern.startswith('^'):
            p_pattern = p_pattern[1:]
        if isinstance(pattern, RegexURLResolver):
            if pattern.namespace:
                namespaces[pattern.namespace] = (p_pattern, pattern)
                if pattern.app_name:
```

Comment: That's a new one on me. I've been using Django CMS for a couple of years now, and I haven't seen that error. I'd contact the devs. They're usually pretty quick to respond to issues.

Comment: I figured out the root of the problem ... didn't like a URL I had in my urls.py. What a strange way to tell me.

Comment: Yes, that's not a very helpful exception!

Comment: @BrianD I'd +1 @Brandons suggestion and contact the devs. Thats an unhelpful exception.

Answer (score 16):

Just had this error.  In my case it was caused by having tripple quoted string (comment) in urls.py patterns.
Actually it was not interpreted as a comment and was passed to function!