# {% url %} not workin in Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-urls, django-templates

I am getting this error `'str' object has no attribute 'regex'` when ever I user `{% url home %}` or any other argument in for that matter in any of my templates.

It seems that any argument that is passed to `url` *is passed as a string*, I am not sure if thats the way url takes its arguments.

Is there anything I am missing here, Am I supposed add any new values to **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS** or **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** or any other.

My **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** are

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
)
```

and **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS** are

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
          'django.core.context_processors.request',
          'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
          'django.core.context_processors.static',
          "django.core.context_processors.media",
          'django.core.context_processors.debug',
          'django.core.context_processors.i18n',)
```

My **myproject/urls.py** is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #Action urls go here
     url(r'^home/$', 'website.home.views.home', name='home'),

    #Contentdeveloper urls go here
     (r'^contentdeveloper/', include('website.contentdeveloper.urls')),

    #Static urls go here
     (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
      {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

My **Views.py** is

```
def home(request):
   return render_to_response('home/home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template code in **home/home.html** is

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% url home %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then the whole **Traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\MirrarOrnamentsWebPortal\website\home\views.py" in home
  19.         return render_to_response('home/home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  411.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  363.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  243.             p_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
```

### Update:

Wired thing happened while debugging, I put a try except block at `django\core\urlresolvers.py` in `_populate` function where the exception occurred and everything magically started working.

I am confused here, is this a django bug or something that I might have done caused the problem.

Comment: show how you defined the url name in routes , and the exact template code too.

Comment: You must paste the full traceback

Comment: @camus I have edited the the question as per what you guys asked

Comment: Do you have any more urls tags in `base.html`?? There is nothing wrong what you have shown so far. So I doubt something wrong in `base.html`

Comment: @AamirAdnan Yes I load my custom template filters in `base.html`, But does that really affect any of my other code.

Comment: What happen if you comment out url? {# url home #} ?

Comment: It works when I comment out url

Comment: Okay, and do I have to comment them out too??

Comment: How about adding another url pattern and reverse that?

Comment: the basic problem here that the url tag is taking its args as a string, so after a lot of calls when it reaches django\core\urlresolvers.py in _populate, in line             `for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns): p_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern`, It does not recognize it.

Comment: Have u tried {% url 'home' %} ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with django url template tag, {% url %}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988661/problems-with-django-url-template-tag-url)

Comment: In your project `urls.py`, home should be `url(r'^home/$', 'home.views.home', name='home'),` minus the project name.  Can you also show your project structure?

Comment: Reminds me of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645661/django-and-django-cms-error  Make sure your other included urls don't have syntax errors, like a string sitting in the pattern... I have my money on this one / have done the same being so used to `''' comments like this '''`

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have used: `{% load url from future %}` and then use `{% url 'home' %}`. You can refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: @anyone who has down-voted. I have no problem with the down-vote, but please do specify what's the mistake here. Even I would get to learn something new or something that I missed.